# What's wrong with this Python file-read test?

Tags: python, file, file-io

What's wrong with this Python file-read test?

```
import os
import sys

fileList = os.listdir(sys.argv[1])
count = 0
for file in fileList:
    try:
        count += 1
        print os.path.isfile(file)
        if os.path.isfile(file)
            print "File >> " + file
        else
            print "Dir >> " + file
    except err:
        print "ERROR: " + err
        print ">> in file: " + file
```

gives:

> File "test.py", line 10
>       if os.path.isfile(file)
>                             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

why?

Comment: Also, [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: @delnan what's the difference of what I'm doing?

Comment: The enumerate function returns a enumerator object which is a list of tuples in the format (index, object), so `list(enumerate(["a", "b"]))` returns `[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b')]`. So you would need to use the count variable. You could use `for count, file in enumerate(fileList):`

Comment: @None looks more complicated than what I just did. Actually, if you're talking about, so it must be better someway, but I'm not understanding in which way it's better..

Comment: It's better in that it's two lines less and plays nicely with `continue`. It's also a matter of using the existing solution instead of doing it yourself. And how is this "more complicated"?

Comment: @delnan I think I'm not understanding how to use enumaration in my example, would be something like `for file in enumerate(fileList)`? If so which are the 2 lines eliminated? Maybe I should read a more complete article explaning the enumeration..

Comment: As None wrote, `for count, file in enumerate(fileList): ...` does the same thing (replaces `count = 0` and `count += 1`). And yes, perhaps you should look for resources on iteration and Python's numerous useful iterators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

missing colon on if and else lines

```
if (something):   #note the : at the end
  ...
else:
  ...
```